# I am trying to show the count and group by using SELECT from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, count, sum

I am trying to show the amount OS and Department per Month and YEAR using the Group By in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(EVT_CODE) AS OS, EVT_MRC AS DEPARTMENT, 
    DATENAME(MONTH, EVT_CREATED) AS MONTH, 
    YEAR(EVT_CREATED) AS YEAR
FROM
    R5EVENTS
GROUP BY 
    EVT_MRC, YEAR(EVT_CREATED), DATENAME(MONTH, EVT_CREATED)
ORDER BY 
    'YEAR' DESC
```

[enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuZct3uZa0tog7dVJI5hEj1KDBe6BQ?e=NA7CET)
I expected these results:
[image]

Comment: You need to `PIVOT` by month to get your desired results,

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: thanks @MartinSmith. a link with the data is inserted

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to PIVOT your table so that the months are column names. The code sample below isn't tested because you provided no sample data.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(EVT_CODE) AS OS, EVT_MRC AS DEPARTMENT, 
    DATENAME(MONTH, EVT_CREATED) AS MONTH, 
    YEAR(EVT_CREATED) AS YEAR
FROM
    R5EVENTS
PIVOT  
(  
    COUNT(EVT_CODE) 
FOR [MONTH] IN
    January, February, March, April, May, June, August, September, October, November, December
) AS p 
GROUP BY 
    EVT_MRC, YEAR(EVT_CREATED), DATENAME(MONTH, EVT_CREATED)
ORDER BY 
    'YEAR' DESC
```

Comment: I was able to find the solution for the code. Thanks!